# Create variable based on condition

Tags: r

Using the `iris` dataset as an example, I am trying to create a new variable that has a different distribution by species.

So, I want to create `new.variable`, based on a random normal distribution, but the parameters will be different for each species.  Here is my latest attempt.  I know that I could split the dataset, add the variable, then put it back together, but that seems unnecessary.

```
set.seed(42)
iris$new.variable <- 0
iris$new.variable[iris$Species == 'setosa'] <- rnorm(nrow(iris[iris$Species == 'setosa']), 5, 1)
iris$new.variable[iris$Species == 'versicolor'] <- rnorm(nrow(iris[iris$Species == 'versicolor']), 10, 2)
iris$new.variable[iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- rnorm(nrow(iris[iris$Species == 'virginica']), 20, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds good to me.

Alternately, you could do something like

```
mns <- c(5, 10, 20)
sds <- 1:3
specNum <- as.numeric(iris$Species)

iris$new.variable <- rnorm(nrow(iris), mns[specNum], sds[specNum])
```

Comment: Ah yes...of course.  This works perfectly.  still confused why I can't just replace a subset at a time...but this solves the problem.  Thank you.